# gradle maven publish via plugin

Tags: java, gradle, maven-publish

I am trying to solve for issue for publishing artifacts - specifically a war file via plugin code.
So here's the problem statement.
We have a gradle projects which uses 'war' plugin to generate project war file and publish it to repo via the maven-publish plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenWeb(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
    }
}
```

So I have developed a plugin which overrides War task and generates another version of the existing war with some modifications.
We need to publish this war also to the artifactory. The catch here is the plugin needs to handle the publishing here rather than the main gradle build file.

Tried various ways, along with configuring the 'publish' task with no luck.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you say that "the plugin needs to handle the publishing here rather than the main gradle build file"? Normally, the Maven publishing plugin should be able to handle any Publication that your plugin has produced.

Comment: I meant the code to do the publishing should be done by the new plugin va the Maven Publishing Plugin. The main build.gradle need not be aware of the publishing of the new war file generate.